Integral of Chebyshev Polynomial
Show that $$ \int_{-1}^{1}x^{6}(1-x^{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}T_{8}(x) dx=0,$$
where $T_{n}(x)=\cos{(n\cos^{-1}(x))}$ (Chebyshev Polynomial).
I have starting with $x=\cos{\theta}$ and then I get some complex integral quantity.
Is there any fast or better approach to solve it?

Since $T_{1}(x)=x, \Rightarrow x^{6}=(T_{1}(x))^{6}$, thus as of orthogonal property of Chebyshev polynomial $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}(T_{1})^{5}(1-x^{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}T_{1}(x)T_{8}(x) dx=0$. Is it correct argument?

What did you get after substituting $x=\cos{\theta}$?

Why don't you write the chebyshev polynomial as an actual polynomial instead of using this cosine definition?

You can isolate $x^6$ in terms of the other even Chebyshev polynomials. As such,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&n=2: T_2(x)=2x^2-T_0(x)\iff x^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(T_2(x)+T_0(x)\right)\\
&n=4: T_4(x)=8x^4-8x^2+T_0(x)\iff x^4=\frac{1}{8}(T_4(x)-T_0(x)+8x^2)\\
&n=6: T_6(x)=32x^6-48x^4+18x^2-T_0(x)\\
&\iff x^6=\frac{1}{32}(T_6(x)+6T_4(x)+15T_2(x)+10T_0(x))
\end{aligned}
$$
Substituting this into the designated integral we'll get a linear combination of inner products of Chebyshev polynomials as the integral includes its weight function $w(x)=(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and the adequate integration limits:
$$\int_{-1}^1x^6T_8(x)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{32}\langle T_6|T_8\rangle+\frac{3}{16}\langle T_4|T_8\rangle+\frac{15}{32}\langle T_2|T_8\rangle+\frac{5}{16}\langle T_0|T_8\rangle$$
Since $\langle T_i | T_j\rangle\propto\delta_{ij}$, the integral turns out to be $0$.

Is answer I stated in my comment also correct?

Not really, the weight function is $(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, not $T_1^5(x)(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
